# Does onNewIntent or onActivityResult get called if the activity is recreated?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

My activity A starts one activity B in another app, and the user can spend quite some time on that activity. During this time, Android could possibly destroy my activity A (perhaps to reclaim memory), I am wondering:

1. If A starts B with `startActivityForResult`, and B calls `setResult` to return to A, If A needs to be recreated, will `onActivityResult` get called after A's `onCreate`?
2. If A starts B with `startActivity`, and B return to A by calling `startActivity` with flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, if A is alive, `onNewIntent` should be called. But if A is destroyed, will `onNewIntent` get called after `onCreate`?

I have read about android activity lifecycle posts on SO, but am not sure about this. And it's not easy to experiment on this.

Comment: On your device, under Settings > System > Developer Options, turn on the "Don't keep activities" option. This will kill activities as soon as you leave them, simulating the system killing it to reclaim memory. Then you can experiment and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

1)It will, but the order of lifecycle calls may be a bit different than you expect.  Be prepared for that possibility.